# BigQuery with Google Spreadsheet error 'Required parameter is missing'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

**UPDATE: This is the fix:**

```
  var request = BigQuery.newQueryRequest();
  request.query = sql

  // Inserts a Query Job
  try {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request,projectNumber);
  }
  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
    return;
  }
```

---

My BigQuery > Google Spreadsheet has been working fine until now, that I'm getting the error 'Required parameter is missing'

The line of code that is throwing the exception is:

```
  try {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(projectNumber, sql, {'timeoutMs':10000});
  }
```

The full code is in this tutorial.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bigquery_tutorial#section2

Has this happened to anyone else? Have you find a solution to this?

Comment: Use the issue tracker to report issues, you'll have a better chance to be seen by who have to.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(projectNumber, sql);
```

do this:

```
var bodyOrResource={
  "kind": "bigquery#queryRequest",
  "query": sql
}
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(bodyOrResource,projectNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a breaking change introduced in the Google *internal* version of appscript that should not affect external customers yet. If you are accessing BigQuery from outside of Google you should not experience this issue (*yet*).

Comment: More details at: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/code-updates-required-for-apps-script.html

Comment: Jordan, can you include the fix in your answer? On the surface, the question looks like it has no solution. Thanks Felipe.

Comment: or a more thorough example, take a look at: https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch12/query.gs